# iOS - Editable Subviews (TextViews, Labels etc) returning null

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield, exc-bad-access

I have written a basic application that puts some textviews on to an external screen. The user can then type messages to be shown in those views and decide which ones are editable etc.

However, whenever I run I check to see if a view is editable, it always returns null.

Code is below:

```
        UITextView *lbl = (UITextView *) [view.subviews objectAtIndex:outputCount];
```

If I do not cast lbl to UITextView, I get null when running:

```
if(lbl.editable)
```

If I do cast it, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, has anyone got any ideas what could be the error?

Cheers guys!

EDIT: Been playing around with it, I believe the bad access is because it is returning null, therefore the if fails. I can print it out fine. How can the editable value be null, though? Surely it must be false or true. If I load the view onto the iPad and touch a textview that has its editable field set to false, it does know. So where is it finding that out?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a specific item from the subviews array instead of an outlet?

Comment: I am only using outlets for Interface Builder and the view is created programatically, would that work? If so, how?

Comment: If you create the view in code, it would be good practice to keep an instance variable for each subview you need to refer to later. I suspect what is happening here is that the subviews array doesn't contain what you think it contains.

Comment: Sorry, wont work for me as there are multiple views at any one time. Plus it should be the same accessing the variables from the array, right?

Comment: At the very least you should keep the text fields in a separate array. My point is that the subviews array is not necessarily the best place - for example, when the keyboard is shown, has the framework just added another subview? I don't know off the top of y head, but it seems possible. Why don't you log the contents of the subviews array before calling your code above and see what is in there?

Answer (score 1):

So, I changed the code to use a UILabel and set the if to check:

```
if(lbl.enabled == YES)
```

And it seems to be running like a dream but now I need to stop the field from greying out when it is not enabled, something which I am sure I will be asking here before the day is out.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: should be worth noting that this does work the UILabel as well, it seems that the enabled/editable variable is returned in some weird way, but the if statement is called, as long as you ensure the enabled value is equal to YES

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't specify where `outputCount` comes from, but it looks like that's probably the problem. If your view has, say, 4 subviews and you attempt to reference `objectAtIndex:4` you will get a null. Perhaps your code should say `[view.subviews objectAtIndex:[outputCount - 1]]` instead. Again, it's not clear where `outputCount` comes from in your code.

Comment: Apologies, output count is set before and, if outputcount is more than the number of subviews, it is set to zero. Sorry, totally forgot to clarify that!

Comment: You probably have this covered, but you need outputCount to be no larger than the number of subviews minus one.